# Primefaces Add and delete Node to tree

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, tree

I want to add  and delete node from primeface tree.

The tree is dynamically populated i.e when you expand it creates the child nodes.

Now I want to add and delete nodes through popup, (when we right click on a node it give option for add or delete). If we choose add, then a popup opens and we are given option to fill the details of the node. Here if we click save the node it's added to the tree under the selected node.

However, in the code below and after the data is filled in the popup dialog, the node is not added and the tree expansion is not working.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

```
    package com.test.primefaces;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
    import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.inject.Named;
    import org.primefaces.event.NodeExpandEvent;
    import org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode;
    import org.primefaces.model.TreeNode;

    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class TreeController implements Serializable {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private TreeNode root;
        private String newNodeName;
        private TreeNode selectedNode;

        @PostConstruct
        public void buildTree() {
            root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);  
            createNode("Node 0", root);
            createNode("Node 1", root);
            createNode("Node 2", root);                        
        }

        public TreeNode getRoot() {
            return root;
        }

        public void setRoot(TreeNode root) {
            this.root = root;
        }

       /* public void addChildNode(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            System.out.println("Selected Node: "+getSelectedNode().toString());
            TreeNode newNode = new DefaultTreeNode("Node New", getSelectedNode());
            getSelectedNode().setExpanded(true);
            }*/

        public void addChildNode() {
            TreeNode newNode = new DefaultTreeNode(newNodeName, getSelectedNode());
            System.out.println("Selected Node: "+getSelectedNode().toString());
            /*TreeNode newNode = new DefaultTreeNode("Node New", getSelectedNode());
            getSelectedNode().setExpanded(true);*/
            }

        public void deleteNode() {
            TreeNode newNode = new DefaultTreeNode(newNodeName, getSelectedNode());
            /*System.out.println("Selected Node: "+getSelectedNode().toString());
            TreeNode newNode = new DefaultTreeNode("Node New", getSelectedNode());
            getSelectedNode().setExpanded(true);*/
            }

        public void onNodeExpand(NodeExpandEvent event) {  
             DefaultTreeNode parent = (DefaultTreeNode) event.getTreeNode();
             if (parent.getChildCount() == 1 && parent.getChildren().get(0).getData().toString().equals("DUMMY")) {
                 parent.getChildren().remove(0);
                 createNode("Node A", parent);
                 createNode("Node B", parent);
                 createNode("Node C", parent);
             }
        }

        private void createNode(String tag, TreeNode parent) {
            TreeNode node = new DefaultTreeNode(tag, parent); 
            // Create Dummy node, just to make the parent node expandable
            new DefaultTreeNode("DUMMY", node);
        }

        public String getNewNodeName() {
            return newNodeName;
        }

        public void setNewNodeName(String newNodeName) {
            this.newNodeName = newNodeName;
        }

        public static long getSerialversionuid() {
            return serialVersionUID;
        }

        public TreeNode getSelectedNode() {
            return selectedNode;
        }

        public void setSelectedNode(TreeNode selectedNode) {
            this.selectedNode = selectedNode;
        }
    }
```

And the xhtml

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <script name="jquery/jquery.js" library="primefaces"></script>
    </h:head>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:tree id="tree" value="#{treeController.root}" var="node"
            dynamic="true" cache="false" selectionMode="single"
            selection="#{treeController.selectedNode}">
            <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{treeController.onNodeExpand}" />
            <p:treeNode>
                <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
            </p:treeNode>
        </p:tree>

        <p:contextMenu for="tree">
            <p:menuitem value="Add Node" update="treeAdd" icon="ui-icon-search"
                oncomplete="PF('treeAddDialog').show()" />
            <p:menuitem value="Delete" update="tree" icon="ui-icon-close"
                actionListener="#{treeController.deleteNode}" />
        </p:contextMenu>

        <p:dialog header="tree node" widgetVar="treeAddDialog" modal="true"
            showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
            <p:outputPanel id="treeAdd" style="text-align:center;">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label,value">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:graphicImage
                            name="demo/images/car/#{dtContextMenuView.selectedCar.brand}-big.gif" />
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:outputLabel for="nodeName" value="NodeName" />
                    <p:inputText id="nodeName" value="#{treeController.newNodeName}"
                        required="true" label="nodename" />

                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{treeController.addChildNode}"
                            value="Save" oncomplete="treeAddDialog.hide();" />
                        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="treeAddDialog.hide();" />
                    </f:facet>


                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:outputPanel>

        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
    </html>
```

Comment: You need to update your expand ajax event.

Comment: Hi Fixed this by replacing  oncomplete="treeAddDialog.hide();" to oncomplete="PF('treeAddDialog').hide;" . Once the dalog diappear the tree is updated, but its not ajax rendered , I need to click the refresh button to have the added node